# Windows Mobile min specs

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there any minimum required hardware specifications for Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC or Windows Mobile 6 Classic.

I know Microsoft has requirements to do with the screen (much be a touch screen etc)

But I am trying to find out if their are Minimum CPU speeds and Flash memory sizes. So I can test against and program to these minimums.

Answer (score 1):

Richer set of results you will be able to find if you try to track down what are hardware requirements for Windows CE 5.0 and [Windows Embedded](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/default.mspx) 6.0. Information is usually associated with Platform Builder tool which is used for building embedded platforms.

As of Windows Mobile, according to [some presentation](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar.recent/vr2007/HAR_WindowsCE.pdf), it can run on 195 MHz with 64MB of RAM.